# SQL query problem

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables Project and ProjectList like this

Project

```
ProjectID
Name
ProjectListID - allow null
```

In ProjectList

```
ProjectListID
ProjName
```

Now what i need here, i want only those recoed from ProjectList table which ProjectListID not in Project table.
I made a query but it is taking lot of time to execute.

```
select * FROM projectslist pl where pl.ProjectsListID not in (SELECT p.ProjectsListID FROM project p where (p.ProjectsListID is not null and p.ProjectsListID <>0))
```

Please help me to create optimize query. I am using My SQL.

Comment: Is `p.ProjectsListID` nullable?

Comment: Do you have any non-nullable column in `projects`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT NULL` condition in your query is redundant: `<> 0` implies it:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    projectslist pl
WHERE   pl.ProjectsListID NOT IN 
        (
        SELECT  p.ProjectsListID
        FROM    project p
        WHERE   p.ProjectsListID <> 0
        )
```

For this to work fast, you need to create an index on `project (ProjectsListID)`.

Could you please run

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT  *
FROM    projectslist pl
WHERE   pl.ProjectsListID NOT IN 
        (
        SELECT  p.ProjectsListID
        FROM    project p
        WHERE   p.ProjectsListID <> 0
        )
```

and post its output here?

**Update:**

Since the column in question is nullable, it is better to rewrite the query as `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    projectslist pl
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    project p
        WHERE   p.ProjectsListID = pl.ProjectsListID
                AND p.ProjectsListID <> 0
        )
```

Comment: 1, 'PRIMARY', 'pl', 'ALL', '', '', '', '', 3827, 'Using where'

Comment: 2, 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'p', 'ALL', '', '', '', '', 1459, 'Using where'

Comment: @Pankaj: could you please create the index and see if the query plan changes?

Comment: can we create index on nullable column also? i also created index on project (ProjectsListID).

Answer (score 2):

ProjectList.ProjectListID is not allow null right?

then you should try to compare by using LEFT JOINS:

```
SELECT * FROM ProjectList pl LEFT JOIN Project p ON pl.ProjectListID = p.ProjectListID
WHERE pl.ProjectListID is null
```

Comment: Or slightly more concise:

    SELECT * FROM ProjectList LEFT JOIN PROJECT USING (ProjectListID)  
    WHERE ProjectList.ProjectListID IS NULL

Comment: This will never return anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
select project_list.*
from project_list left join project using (project_list_id)
where isnull(project.project_id)
```

This query is much faster than the solutions provided by others using subquery.

Comment: This query would be slower if `project` is `MyISAM` and there is no composite index on `(project_list_id, project_id)`. In general, `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` and `NOT IN` perform equally well in `MySQL`: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: well the first step in query optimization is schema optimization, which involves creating relevant indexes :) so i presume since a column is being used to filter results so most of the times it should be a part of the key :)